# changing MIPS function value to an integer value and excuting in QtSpim

Tags: mips, qtspim

This is the c language which I changed to MIPS

```
int fact(int n){

   if(n<1) return(1);
   else return n*(n-1);}
}
```

```
    .text
main:

fact:   addi $sp, $sp, -8
    sw $ra, 4($sp)
    sw $a0, 0($sp)

    slti $t0, $a0, 1
    beq $t0, $zero, L1

    addi $v0, $zero, 1
    addi $sp, $sp, 8
    jr $ra


L1:     addi $a0, $a0, -1
    jal fact

    lw $a0, 0($sp) 
    lw $ra, 4($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 8
    
    mul $v0, $a0, $v0
    jr $ra
```

this is my MIPS code.
If I wanna change the value of n to 5 and excute it to see what the result is in QtSpim which part would I change in the MIPS code

Comment: What do you mean by "changing" it? You're currently never calling `fact` at all. Well, unless you count falling into it with some random value for `n` (or zero, depending on the simulator).

Comment: Your C code is broken.  Starting assembly from broken C or pseudo code that doesn't work is a recipe for frustration.

Comment: This code requires a `main` to invoke the function.  This part is missing.  Imagine testing the C version in a program.  How would you do that?  Add a main that calls fact.